# Cannot select input layers for the "Polygonize" tool in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, polygonize, file-path

I am trying to convert a raster layer to a polygon layer using QGIS 3.16. 2. When I open the polygonize tool, the program does not allow me to select any existing raster layers from the 'Input layer' drop-down menu.

I have tried manually selecting the raster from my computer (a .TIF tile), but just get the following message:

[image: Dialog box]

The Log Messages window does't seem to offer any further information, at least in the OGR tab, reading:

```
2021-01-16T11:42:49     WARNING    Cannot open C:/Users/User/Desktop/GBG_slope.tif.()
```

I am not sure what's happening here. What potential ways can I solve this issue?

Comment: Aren't you trying `Polygonize` under the *Vector geometry*? Try `Polygonize (raster to vector)` under the *GDAL > Raster conversion* instead.

Comment: Polygonize (raster to vector) creates a series of pixel polygons. I could be misremembering, but I thought Polygonize could create "smoother" polygons. 

The files when using Polygonize (raster to vector) are also very large, since every single pixel becomes a polygon.

Comment: @Kazuhito, you are correct.

`Polygonize (raster to vector)` is the tool I was looking for. 

I have also discovered that there is a `Raster pixels to polygons` option which works quite a bit faster than the GDAL alternative.

For future reference, `Polygonize (raster to vector)` and `Raster pixels to polygons` appear to perform similar functions. 

`Polygonize` is a separate tool entirely, it seems.

If you post as an answer, I will mark it as resolved.

Comment: `Raster pixels to polygons` converts each pixel into a small polygon. `Polygonize (raster to vector)` also merges adjacent polygons which have the same value as the pixel value attribute into larger polygons.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you search for `Polygonize` in the Processing Toolbox, there appear several tools.

[image]

**1) [Polygonize](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#polygonize)** tool converts line layer to polygon layer, turning an area inside three line segments into a polygon. This tool takes line vector layers as input.

[image]

**2) [Polygonize (raster to vector)](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdal/rasterconversion.html#polygonize-raster-to-vector)** converts raster into vector polygons. If adjacent pixels have same value, they are grouped into the same polygon.

[image]

**3) [Raster pixels to polygons**](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorcreation.html#raster-pixels-to-polygons) creates a rectangle polygon for each raster pixel. Similar tool `Raster pixels to points` creates a centroid point for each raster pixel.

[image]

So the tool you need would probably be `Polygonize (raster to vector)`. However, you would better reclassify your raster into reasonable number of classes before doing Polygonize operation.